# Adfs ECC certificate-based authentication

Tags: active-directory, adfs, ecc

Is it possible to use client authentication with ECC certification?

Our ADFS szervers (Win server 2016 with .net 4.7.1) is always throw a key algorithm not supported exception: System.NotSupportedException: The certificate key algorithm is not supported

at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.PublicKey.get_Key()

...

I did not find MS documentation for supported certification public keys for CBA.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The elliptical curve cipher suites available for and enabled by default for Windows Server 2016 are published in the following article.

The availability factors in the operating system version, TLS versions, and other various relevant system settings.

Note that newer ciphers available in 2022 and 2019 are typically not backported and not available in 2016.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/tls-cipher-suites-in-windows-10-v1607

---

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/cipher-suites-in-schannel

---

[image: Windows Cipher Suites]

---

Windows Server 2016 has the following curves enabled: Curve25519, NistP256, and NistP384. Other curve strings are supported but not enabled by default. Group Policy may be used to configure the required curves described in the following article.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/tls-elliptic-curves-in-windows-10-1607-and-later